# How to export oracle database version 12.1.0.2.0 with expdp Release 12.2.0.1.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-12c, dump, expdp

I am running following command to dump my database

```
./expdp username/password@//host:port/database directory=/home/ubuntu/oracle/instantclient_12_2 dumpfile=dumpfilename.dmp content=METADATA_ONLY
```

and getting following error

```
Export: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Sep 14 06:14:28 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
UDE-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 12.1.0.2.0
```

I tried searching and there were suggestion to use `VERSION` parameter which I did still no success.

Does anyone have idea what should i do to overcome the issue?

I cant use `instantclient-tools-macos.x32-12.1.0.2.0.zip` as it doesnt have `expdp` command.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure about the target and source version?
I did here and worked right.
My source DB version was 12.1.0.2.0 and the target was 12.2.0.1.0.
Please, see my example below:

```
$ cat myfile.par
directory=DUMP
dumpfile=MYFILE.DMP
logfile=MYFILE.LOG
content=ALL
schemas="DIEGO","HR","USER"

$ expdp user@mypdb parfile=myfile.par
```

[Exporting and Importing Between Different Database Releases](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-BAA3B679-A758-4D55-9820-432D9EB83C68.htm#SUTIL110)

> In an **upgrade** situation, when the target release of a Data Pump-based migration is higher than the source, the VERSION parameter typically does not have to be specified because all objects in the source database will be compatible with the higher target release. An exception is when an entire Oracle Database 11g (release 11.2.0.3 or higher) is exported in preparation for importing into Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.1) or later. In this case, explicitly specify VERSION=12 in conjunction with FULL=YES in order to include a complete set of Oracle internal component metadata.
>
> In a **downgrade** situation, when the target release of a Data Pump-based migration is lower than the source, the VERSION parameter should be explicitly specified to be the same version as the target. An exception is when the target release version is the same as the value of the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter on the source system; then VERSION does not need to be specified. In general however, Data Pump import cannot read dump file sets created by an Oracle release that is newer than the current release unless the VERSION parameter is explicitly specified.

Answer (score 1):

[Export/Import DataPump Parameter VERSION - Compatibility of Data Pump Between Different Oracle Versions [Video] (Doc ID 553337.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=553337.1)

> ```
> Data Pump client compatibility.
> ===============================
>
>    expdp and  Connecting to Database version
> impdp client     10gR1      10gR2      11gR1      11gR2      12cR1      12cR2        18c
>      version  10.1.0.x   10.2.0.x   11.1.0.x   11.2.0.x   12.1.0.x   12.2.0.x   18.x.y.z
> ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
>    10.1.0.x  supported  supported  supported  supported         no         no         no
>    10.2.0.x         no  supported  supported  supported  supported         no         no
>    11.1.0.x         no  supported  supported  supported  supported         no         no
>    11.2.0.x         no         no         no  supported  supported  supported  supported
>    12.1.0.x         no         no         no         no  supported  supported  supported
>    12.2.0.x         no         no         no         no         no  supported  supported
>    18.x.y.z         no         no         no         no         no         no  supported
> ```

Use a 10.2.0.x - 12.1.0.x version client.

Comment: I tried `instantclient-tools-macos.x32-12.1.0.2.0.zip ` but it doesnt contain `expdp`. I am not sure how can do that using `10.2.0.x` to `12.1.0.x` version

Comment: @BhaskarDabhi 1. You can download the full client at: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-linux-download-2240591.html 2. You do not even need expdp on client side, you can just log in to the database and use DBMS_DATAPUMP 3. The value of directory parameter you provided will not work, it needs to be a directory object defined in the database that points to a directory accessible on the database server.

Comment: Do you mean i have to do

SQL> CREATE DIRECTORY dmpdir AS '/rdbms/work';
SQL> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY dmpdir TO user;
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

then replace `directory=/home/ubuntu/oracle/instantclient_12_2 ` with `directory=/rdbms/work` in my above command and run it?

Comment: @BhaskarDabhi `directory=dmpdir`

Comment: You do not "have to replace directory=/home/ubuntu/oracle/instantclient_12_2 with directory=/rdbms/work".  A db directory object ('dmpdir' in this case) is just an internal alias for *a* (as in "any")  OS directory.  It doesn't matter what os directory is referenced by 'dmpdir', as long as that directory exists and has the correct OS permissions.  Also, SERVEROUTPUT has nothing to do with any of this.

Comment: ohh ok got it @EdStevens thnx

Comment: @BalazsPapp, also issue is that i dont know the os directory structure as i dont have permission to do ssh on the machine. how can i handle this in this situation?